# _expand_alias widget seems to be missing from ZLE

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm trying to auto-expand aliases as I type in zsh using the [globalias](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/globalias) plugin from oh-my-zsh. It was working when I first installed the plugin, but now it has broken. I think it broke after I rearranged the lines in my `~/.zshrc` but I'm not sure.

I've tried to simplify the problem by removing everything except the following lines form my `~/.zshrc` (I got this from [a reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/zsh/comments/bbbluo/auto_expand_all_aliases_by_pressing_space/ekhpxer/) but it also looks v similar to the [function in the globalias plugin](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/plugins/globalias/globalias.plugin.zsh)):

```
function expand-alias() {
    zle _expand_alias
    zle self-insert
}
zle -N expand-alias
bindkey -M main ' ' expand-alias
```

When I source this file and type a space in my prompt, I see

```
No such widget `_expand_alias'
```

I've tried googling and it seems like `_expand_alias` should be a built-in ZLE function, but when I look for it with `zle -la | grep _expand_alias` it's not there.

I'm not sure what to try next? I can't find a way to reset zsh or the built-in ZLE commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by adding the line `autoload -Uz compinit && compinit` near the start of my `~/.zshrc`.

Hope this helps someone!